# Issue with Apps Script between sheets and calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create events from a sheet of a column of dates and a column of data.

I'm getting hung up on this error message:

> Cannot find method createAllDayEventSeries(string,string,string). (line 14, file "Code")

My code is attached in the screenshot, and for the most part I followed the Gsuite tutorial online, even though I used allday event code as I do not have times in my sheet.

Any clue as to where I'm going wrong?

[image: screenshot of my code]

Comment: Welcome. Code should be added as text, not as image.

Comment: I'd guess the second parameter is not date and the third is possibly not a recurrence.  Try `var Date=new  Date(shift[0]);` and see if the  error changes. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createAllDayEventSeries(String,Date,EventRecurrence)) Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parameters are of the wrong type. According to  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventseriestitle,-startdate,-recurrence

Parameters

```
Name        Type                Description
title       String              the title of the events in the series
startDate   Date                the date of the first event in the series (only the day is used; the time is ignored)  
recurrence  EventRecurrence     the recurrence settings of the event series
```

but you script is passing all the parameters as Strings

Related

- [Create Google Calendar Recurring Events from Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25515765/1595451)
- [Creating recurring Google Calendar events from Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25895337/1595451)
- [Create Recurring All Day Calendar Event from List of Dates in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58654019/1595451)